# Disable "all pubs" selected as scope when creating/editing users in SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: tridion

Is there any configuration one can to do prevent the auto-population of group scope when creating users in SDL Tridion 2013?

When selecting a group for a user in the CMS GUI, default will be all publications set as scope. And it is irritating to manually undo all. It takes time when you have a large volume of publications. We got some tools that creates users for us but sometime, you need to work in the CMS GUI and you just waste so much time.

But can there be a way to "work" around that crappy option they did develop into the CMS?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a configuration setting, you would probably need to write a GUI Extension (which is not that simple), but see below for a helpfull tip.

Press `CTRL + A`

- this will select all the boxes

Then press `SPACEBAR`

- this will toggle them on or off.

That is the quickest way I know. You might consider asking this over at http://tridion.stackexchange.com